# R - Function Error with IF Statement

Tags: r, function, if-statement

I am getting the following error for the code: Error: unexpected '}' in "}"

```
csv_etl <- function(client) {
  if (client = 'OXF') {
    print('I am OXF')
  }
}
```

Is my syntax incorrect? I've counted the curly braces and parenthesis and they all are closed.

Comment: This is a common error in R. The equal sign `=` is the assignment operator in R. the test for equality is the double equal sign `==`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a double equal sign:

```
csv_etl <- function(client) {
  if (client == 'OXF') {
    print('I am OXF')
  }
}
```